# POSTMAN- Test Validation

Tags: testing, postman

I would like to write a postman test for the below response if the "relatedDecisionTreeQuestionUID": "c68252d0-3f88-e911-a98e-12345600cf35"  then display "questionText" as Blocked and UnBlocked.

Please can someone help with the javascript

":

```
[
            {
                "estimationDuration": "0",
                "jobTypeUId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "jobType": null,
                "relatedDecisionTreeQuestionUID": "c68252d0-3f88-e911-a98e-12345600cf35",
                "priorityUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "priority": "",
                "decisionTreeUID": "d73657e8-3f88-e911-a98e-11334800cf12",
                "workOrderTypeUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "workOrderType": "",    
                "questionText": "Blocked”,
                "childQuestions": [
": [
            {
                "estimationDuration": "0",
                "jobTypeUId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "jobType": null,
                "relatedDecisionTreeQuestionUID": " c68252d0-3f88-e911-a98e-12345600cf35",
                "priorityUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "priority": "",
                "decisionTreeUID": "d73657e8-3f88-e911-a98e-00224800cf35",
                "workOrderTypeUID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "workOrderType": "",    
                "questionText": " UnBlocked ",
                "childQuestions": [
```

Comment: I have pm.test("test", function () {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  jsonData.filter(function(item){
      if(item.relatedDecisionTreeQuestionUID==="c68252d0-3f88-e911-a98e-12345600cf35"){
          console.log(item.questionText);
      }
  })

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
pm.test("test", function() {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  jsonData.filter(function(item) {
     if (item.relatedDecisionTreeQuestionUID === " c68252d0-3f88-e911-a98e-12345600cf35") {
        console.log(item.questionText);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I got this error, 
test | TypeError: jsonData.filter is not a function